# How create a topBar with submenus in asp.net boilerplate template

Tags: asp.net, navigation, boilerplate

I'm trying to create a topbar with submenus using asp.net boilerplate template
but i can't do it.

the structure is

- reports

  - aggregates
  - raws
- Graphics.

I have this documentation http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Navigation
but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's included in startup template.
See this topic on the forum: http://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=135